# How do I return to my app after opening up another app?

Tags: iphone, maps

i have a webview in my iphone app where a google map location is opened like;

[Directions](http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=San+Francisco,+CA&saddr=cupertino)

now the google map native app opens fine, but how could i add a RETURN button so it would jump back to my html page. Now i have to click my home button and the app close back to the desktop, so i have to start my webview again.

in android its more easy, because there is always a back button and after viewing my gmap i simply back in my webview.

thx
chris

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a map then use MKMapKit to embed the maps directly into your own app. This is the only way you will be able to return to your views. Linking out via a URL will kill your application off (no multitasking).

The first example I worked through was this one http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2009/04/02/iphone-sdk-30-playing-with-map-kit/ (although there may be other/better/more recent examples now).

Andrew